# how to store data locally in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have many form in my application I want to store data locally when net is not available.
and if net is available then send to server.
please let me know how to implement this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Core Data, SQLite with FMDB, plist serialisation of just plain and simple [NSCoding](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data).

Answer (score 0):

You can use core-data to store the data locally for iPhone.

[Introduction to Core Data](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/)

SQLite is also good but i`ll prefer core data.

Comment: I want to store data temporary when net connectivity is available i have to send data to server and clean local data base.

Comment: Check the link may be helpful you can synch data if you want to delete you can also delete the data no issue. 

http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1